# Modifying adwaita dark theme on 18.04

Tags: windows, themes, gtk, colors

im wondering if there is a way to change the adwaita dark theme a little bit i found some really useful info on here about changing dock and top bar components and have successfully changed it to black backgrounds with red text and i want to make the windows match. -TIA